# Android TransitionDrawbale disabling other ways to change backggroun

Tags: android

I have code to change background of EditText through TextWatcher like this:

```
  etPin1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            switch (etPin1.length()){

                case 0:
                    etPin1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.zero);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    etPin1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.one);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    etPin1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.two);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    etPin1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.three);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    etPin1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.four);
                   // getPassowrdAgain(s.toString());
                    validateAndProceed(s.toString(),view);
                    break;

            }


        }
    });
```

but when error occurs I need to show some short animation by showing red background in the EditText for short time and reset it.Here is the code for that purpose:

```
 Drawable backgrounds[] = new Drawable[2];
        Resources res = getResources();
        backgrounds[0] = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.zero);
        backgrounds[1] = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.error_pin);
        TransitionDrawable crossfader = new TransitionDrawable(backgrounds);

        etPin1.setBackgroundDrawable(crossfader);

        crossfader.startTransition(3000);

     // Reverse transition
        crossfader.reverseTransition(3000);
```

Now the once the crossfader works fine when I try to change the text and expect the change in background its not happening. Should I remove the the crossfader or what if so how can I do that.
**Its not even calling the textwatcher after that**

Comment: just call `crossfader.startTransition(3000);` only

Comment: @pskink I have tried it, didn't work  can you explain why you suggested that

Comment: because starting transition two times in a row makes no sense,  see the sources on how it works

Comment: also calling `reverseTransition` just after `startTransition` has no effect, please see the sources, if you cannot use `TransitionDrawable` directly, write your custom `Drawable` that works the way you want: it should be done in less than 50 lines of code

Comment: ust checked that: the basic `MultiTransitionDrawable` takes 20 lines of effective code, i would post `MultiTransitionDrawable` code but it seems you are not interested, so...

Comment: Please post me the code as your answer..

Comment: since you were not interested i already deleted that snippet, just create custom `Drawable` and implement `ObjectAnimator` inside, it is easy